# Is there a way for reading a redis list in bulks?

Tags: python, redis, batch-processing

Assume we have a redis set with hundreds thousands elements in it. As `smember` command does eager-loading, it fetches all of the elements just by this **one command** and consequently it consumes too much time. I want to know is there a way to read redis data as bulks or maybe as a stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Bulks

Data from Redis `Set` data structure can be read in bulks using [SSCAN](https://redis.io/commands/sscan) command.

```
> sadd set a
(integer) 1
> sadd set b
(integer) 1
> sadd set c
(integer) 1

> SMEMBERS set
1) "c"
2) "b"
3) "a"

> SSCAN set 0 COUNT 2
1) "1"                  // <-- cursor for following SSCAN
2) 1) "b"
   2) "a"
> SSCAN set 1 COUNT 2   // <-- cursor from previous SSCAN
1) "0"                  // <-- cursor=0 indicating complete iteration
2) 1) "c"
```

---

#### Stream

There is no direct support from Redis to stream `Set` structure data.